# Convert vector from string to integer

Tags: java, vector

Is there some method to convert a `Vector<String>` to a `Vector<Integer>` in Java ?

I am getting a string vector:

```
final Vector<String> partitions = (Vector<String>) properties.get(index);
```

The value is an index value which is an integer, always. I need to convert this string into integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to manually convert it

```
Vector<String> strings = ..
Vector<Integer> ints = ...

for(String s : strings) {
    ints.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The method is to iterate over the sting vector, parse each element to put the result to the int vector:

```
List<Integer> intList = ....;
for (String s : strList) {
    intList.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
}
```

If you want to write this as single line take a look on [LambdaJ](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/).

EDIT: and *please* forget about existing of Vector and Hashtable. Use ArrayList and HashMap instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it, other than looping thru the whole array and doing the cast yourself and then adding to the vector again.